# Get all method with annotation @Test in all class in all JAR Files

Tags: java, junit, reflection

I want take all mehod with @Test in all JAR file with many class.
i have my main in `src/main/java/it/anas/testsuiteloader/controller.java`
and jar file in `src/main/java/test/*`   <---test is a package

my code is:

```
             //TAKE ALL JAR FILE
             List<JarFile> jarList = Files.walk(Paths.get("src/main/java/test"))
            .filter(f -> f.toString().endsWith(".jar"))
            .map(Path::toFile).map(f -> {
                try {
                    return new JarFile(f);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

     //in all jar, in all class in all method

     for (JarFile j : jarList) {
         for (Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = j.entries(); entries.hasMoreElements(); ) {
            JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
            String file = entry.getName();

            if (file.endsWith(".class")) {
                String classname = file.replaceAll("/", ".")
                        .substring(0, file.lastIndexOf("."));


                try {
                    Class<?> currentClass = Class.forName(classname); <----ERROR!!!!
                    List<String> testMethods = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < currentClass.getMethods().length; i++) {
                        Method method = currentClass.getMethods()[i];
                        Annotation ann = method.getAnnotation(Test.class);
                        if (ann != null) {
                            testMethods.add(method.getName());
                        }
                    }//fine for metodi
                    if (testMethods.size() >1) {
                        testClassObjList.put(j.toString(),classname,testMethods);
                        System.out.format("%s %s %s",j.toString(),classname,testMethods);
                    }
                } catch (Throwable e) {System.out.println("WARNING: failed to instantiate " + classname + " from " + file); }

            }
        }
```

It take correct class name:

```
String classname = file.replaceAll("/", ".")
                        .substring(0, file.lastIndexOf("."));  //<----- IS OK i view here class name
```

But here i have error:

```
Class<?> currentClass = Class.forName(classname);  //<-----ERROR no class found!
```

Some TIPS???
How i search class in JAR file??
thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You open a jar file (jar is an archive in zip format) and iterate over the entries in the archive. Your problem is that you never loaded your jar to the JVM, so `Class.forName` will fail.

You need to load your jar file dynamically.
Here is my code for finding annotations in one class for dynamically loaded jar, inspired by [How to load JAR files dynamically at Runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-to-load-jar-files-dynamically-at-runtime)

```
var url = new File("YOUR_JAR.jar").toURI().toURL();
var child = new URLClassLoader(
        new URL[] {url},
        this.getClass().getClassLoader()
);
var classToLoad = Class.forName("YOUR_CLASS_FULLY_QUALIFIED_NAME", true, child);
var methods = classToLoad.getMethods();
for (var method: methods) {
    Annotation ann = method.getAnnotation(Test.class);
    if (ann != null) {
        System.out.println("method: " + method.getName());
    }
}
```

You can easily extend that to process multiple classes and multiple jars.